# imagemagick -auto-level in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

I've been looking for a solution to perform the equivalent of `magick -auto-level` in ffmpeg but am unable to find anything. There are some references stating I should first manually discover the levels using other software like GIMP, however, I'm looking for an automated and simpler solution. Any ideas how to address this?

I've tried the following - the first enhanced the image which was initially prettry dark, but the second over-exposed it, causing it to become mostly white:

```
convert img.jpg -auto-level img2.jpg
ffmpeg -i img.jpg -vf "normalize" -y img2.jpg
```

Note: I apologize I cannot share the image as it is restricted by privacy policy

Comment: `normalize` looks close https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#normalize

Comment: tried that. got completely different results. Magick did improve the image (which was a a bit dark) but ffmpeg -vf "normalize" entirely over-exposed it. I could get close with `-vf "normalize=strength=0.25"` but the whole point is that I don't want to arbitrarily add parameters because it may vary between images

Comment: Can you click [edit] and add the actual, full command you used please?

Comment: Adding an input image, and your expected and actual corresponding output image would also help.

Comment: commands added in original question